# Show popup window when in fullscreen mode on MacOS

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

#### Background

We are building a cross-platform application with "popup" reminders, they are custom windows/dialogs which uses [`QWidget.setWindowFlags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) like this:

```
self.setWindowFlags(
    QtCore.Qt.Dialog
    | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
    | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint
)
```

These popups show up on the systems we have tested (MacOS, Lubuntu (LXDE)), even when we switch between different virtual desktops the dialogs are still shown in the current desktop. However:

#### Problem

When the user is **in fullscreen mode on MacOS** (Sierra 10.12.6) the dialog instead is shown in the last virtual desktop that was used

#### Question

**How can we show our "popup" dialogs to the user even when the user is in fullscreen mode on MacOS?**

Comment: Have you tried the flag `Qt::Tool`?

Comment: @mschmidt Hi, i've now gotten a response from my friend who is using MacOS, she says that unfortunately the problem is still there after using `Qt:Tool`. We're still looking for a solution, any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Did you try Qt::Popup?

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that you can't and neither can any other app.

Here's why.

The idea is that when you select the fullscreen view for an app, you want to focus exclusively on that app, to the exclusion of all others.  So the app not only expands to fill the entire screen, it removes the menu bar and creates its own desktop space.

You can see how this works using Mission Control (by default, swipe up with 3 fingers).  You will see all the apps and all the desktops across all your monitors.  Next, set an app to full screen and swipe up again.  You'll see that the app has a dedicated desktop (which I believe doesn't even have wallpaper).

The bottom line is that macOS fullscreen view does not support pop-ups.

Comment: How does spotlight work then?

Comment: [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) is also able to pop over fullscreen applications. Some Electron developers [also seem to have figured it out](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10078).